# Fan constantly runs on Dell on Ubuntu

Tags: graphics, 15.04, dell, radeon, fan

My laptop configuration are
Dell 3521
Core i3  3227U @ 1.9Ghz
4GB RAM
Intel HD4000 graphic + radeon HD7670m 1GB DDR3 dedicated graphics.

When I boot Ubuntu 14.04.02LTS on my laptop, CPU cooling fan starts to run continuously at max speed making a loud sound while the laptop is in idle state :( and also the air blown out side is not hot, just normal air. I Constantly updated my OS but nothing stops the fan running at max speed. So I thought that Open source driver is the problem so I tried fglrx proprietary driver through the additional hardware. But still the same problem exists. Then I moved to Ubuntu 14.10 and installed the available intel driver at 01.org, but still the problem is not solved. Then Today I installed Ubuntu 15.04 with fglrx proprietary driver, but still the problem is unsolved. Please guys tell me how to fix this as soon as possible.
Thanks

Here it is

---

```
root@kasun-Inspiron-3521:/home/kasun# lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0598
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] (rev ff)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0598

root@kasun-Inspiron-3521:/home/kasun#
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: It does not look like you installed fglrx driver? How did you install it?

Comment: by using the additional drivers at the Software and updates

Comment: please can anyone help me with this issue, I am really bored with the fan noise and couldnot do any work. So please help :(

Comment: Please run in terminal `sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates`. If there are any errors post output to your question.

Comment: Ok I am running it now and let you know if any proceed

Comment: I did it, then once I logout the machine, it said, Your machine is low on graphic memory.  there were options like these   1. reconfigure graphics 2. try default driver....   like those options :(

Comment: PLease guys help me

Comment: Today I installed Ubuntu 15.10, and as the same problem was occured again, I installed i8kutil in my PC. After installing my fan stopped completely, like it is freezen. when some work is performed which surely need the fan to running, it is not spinnig, just keep slient. And after installing i8kutil I still couldn't get the so called gui interface of it, as said in many post in the internet. plz guys I am sick of this issue, just give me a good solution plz... It is really annoying to work like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using i8kutil package which is used for controlling the fans in Dell laptops.

Use this solution found at this webpage: [How to solve Dell laptops fan issues in Ubuntu](http://keenformatics.blogspot.com.tr/2013/06/how-to-solve-dell-laptops-fan-issues-in.html).

I used this config for my Dell 3521 with Radeon HD7670M 1GB dedicated graphics.

```
# Sample i8kmon configuration file (/etc/i8kmon.conf, ~/.i8kmon).
# External program to control the fans
set config(i8kfan)  /usr/bin/i8kfan
# Run as daemon, override with --daemon option
set config(daemon) 0
# Automatic fan control, override with --auto option
set config(auto) 1
set config(nouserconfig) 1
# Applet geometry, override with --geometry option
set config(geometry)    {48x48}
# Report status on stdout, override with --verbose option
set config(verbose) 1
# Status check timeout (seconds), override with --timeout option
set config(timeout) 5
# Temperature display unit (C/F), override with --unit option
set config(unit)    C
# Temperature threshold at which the temperature is displayed in red
set config(t_high)  80
# Temperature thresholds: {fan_speeds low_ac high_ac low_batt high_batt}
# These were tested on the I8000. If you have a different Dell laptop model
# you should check the BIOS temperature monitoring and set the appropriate
# thresholds here. In doubt start with low values and gradually rise them
# until the fans are not always on when the cpu is idle.
set config(0)   {{-1 0}  -1  60  -1  65}
set config(1)   {{-1 1}  50  70  55  75}
set config(2)   {{-1 1}  60  80  65  85}
set config(3)   {{-1 2}  70 128  75 128}
# end of file
```

After configuring run this in terminal on every boot up:

```
i8kmon --auto --verbose --nouserconfig
```